# XSLT transformation from flat structure to nested

Tags: xslt

I cannot manage with simple (?) XSLT Transformation.

There is an input flat-structured XML:

```
<root>
    <attribute_a>abc</attribute_a>
    <attribute_b>def</attribute_b>
    <attribute_c>ghi</attribute_c>
    <attribute_a>123</attribute_a>
    <attribute_b>456</attribute_b>
    <attribute_c>789</attribute_c>
    <attribute_a>xxx</attribute_a>
    <attribute_b>xxx</attribute_b>
    <attribute_c>xxx</attribute_c>
</root>
```

I should transform it to an XML like this:

```
<root>
    <attribute>
        <attribute_a>abc</attribute_a>
        <attribute_b>def</attribute_b>
        <attribute_c>ghi</attribute_c>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attribute_a>123</attribute_a>
        <attribute_b>456</attribute_b>
        <attribute_c>789</attribute_c>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attribute_a>xxx</attribute_a>
        <attribute_b>xxx</attribute_b>
        <attribute_c>xxx</attribute_c>
    </attribute>
</root>
```

But the problem is after transformation like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/attribute_a">
                <attribute>
                    <attribute_a>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../attribute_a" />
                    </attribute_a>
                    <attribute_b>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../attribute_b" />
                    </attribute_b>
                    <attribute_c>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../attribute_c" />
                    </attribute_c>
                </attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i got something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <attribute>
        <attribute_a>abc</attribute_a>
        <attribute_b>def</attribute_b>
        <attribute_c>ghi</attribute_c>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attribute_a>abc</attribute_a>
        <attribute_b>def</attribute_b>
        <attribute_c>ghi</attribute_c>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attribute_a>abc</attribute_a>
        <attribute_b>def</attribute_b>
        <attribute_c>ghi</attribute_c>
    </attribute>
</root>
```

I am not very experienced in XSLT - do you have any ideas? :(

regards,
A. M.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for a well-structured first question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="root/attribute_a">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates
            select="../attribute_a[$pos] | 
                    ../attribute_b[$pos] |
                    ../attribute_c[$pos]" />
        </attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I'd suggest taking it one step further and using a separate template instead of a `for-each`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/attribute_a" mode="group" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="attribute_a" mode="group">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="../attribute_a[$pos] | ../attribute_b[$pos] | ../attribute_c[$pos]" />
    </attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When either of these XSLTs is run on your sample input, it produces this output:

```
<root>
  <attribute>
    <attribute_a>abc</attribute_a>
    <attribute_b>def</attribute_b>
    <attribute_c>ghi</attribute_c>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
    <attribute_a>123</attribute_a>
    <attribute_b>456</attribute_b>
    <attribute_c>789</attribute_c>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
    <attribute_a>xxx</attribute_a>
    <attribute_b>xxx</attribute_b>
    <attribute_c>xxx</attribute_c>
  </attribute>
</root>
```